# Sign languages spoken in Italy

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, regional, history, single-words

What sign languages spoken in Italy can be regarded as Italian sign languages and what are the sign languages spoken in Italy called (in Italian)?

Comment: "Lingua dei segni italiana" at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Sign_Language,   https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_dei_segni_italiana

Comment: @Charo, why don't you put it as answer? I think everything he needs is in the link...

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: OK, I'll do it. But I don't like the answers that consist only in some links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from Wikipedia, the sign language used in Italy is called "lingua dei segni italiana". You can find more information about this sign language at these Wikipedia articles:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Sign_Language
- https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_dei_segni_italiana